# Were can i find the original old releases of ubuntu 8.04.0 without any viruses

Tags: usb, system-installation

Were can i find the original old releases of ubuntu any viruses?
Please respond If you know.

Comment: official page: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/

Answer (score 0):

The older releases of Ubuntu are indeed a bit buried through a few links.

You can find older releases here

- [Ubuntu older releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/)

and specifically

- [Ubuntu 8.04 Hardy Heron](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/)